# AutoGenerate a uuid and use a part of it to update another column in a single postgres query statement

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

I have two columns in lets say employees table.
1) emp_id which is a uuid autogenerated.
2) emp_name which is a string.

Now i want to put some default values in emp_name column at the time of insert and i want lets say first 6 characters of the corresponding emp_id added after 'emp_' string.
And i want all of it as a single insert query statement.
Is there a way to do such a thing in postgres.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH emp as (SELECT public.gen_random_uuid() AS uuid)
insert into employees(emp_id, emp_name) (select 
emp.uuid,'emp_'||substring(emp.uuid::varchar from 0 for 6) from emp);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the uuid, save it in a variable and use it in the insert statement.
To understand how you can create it and the different type of uuid, you can read this page:

http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-uuid/